# Need to convert SAML response to SecurityToken object in .net 6

Tags: .net, soap, saml

I have a legacy system in .net 4.5 and i am upgrading it to .net 6. The system is communicating with third party SOAP service which requires SecurityToken. Another entity is responsible for issuing the token which WS-Trust service. I came to know that the .net 5+ has limited functionality so i had to use HttpClient instead of WSTrustChannelFactory and i am constructing the Header and Body manually. I have successfully called the token service and the response is a SOAP message. Now i want to convert this message to System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityToken but i cannot find any method to do this. I am attaching legacy code as well as new code.

**Legacy Code**

```
public static IUSIService OpenWithM2M()
{
    var token = GetStsToken(60);
    var clientSection = (ClientSection) ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.serviceModel/client");
    var endpointElement = clientSection.Endpoints.OfType<ChannelEndpointElement>()
        .First(endpoint => string.Equals("USIServiceReference.IUSIService", endpoint.Contract, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    if (endpointElement == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("No endpoint matching service contract was found");
    }

    var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IUSIService>(endpointElement.Name);
    channelFactory.Open();
    return channelFactory.CreateChannelWithIssuedToken(token);
}

private static SecurityToken GetStsToken(int tokenLifeTimeMinutes)
{
    var factory = new WSTrustChannelFactory("S007SecurityTokenServiceEndpoint");
    if (factory.Credentials != null)
    {
        factory.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = GetClientCertificateFromKeystore();

        // Instantiate and invoke the client to get the security token
        factory.Credentials.SupportInteractive = false;
    }

    var appliesTo = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["appliesTo"];
    var rst = new RequestSecurityToken
    {
        Claims =
        {
            new RequestClaim("http://vanguard.ebusiness.gov.au/2008/06/identity/claims/abn", false),
            new RequestClaim("http://vanguard.ebusiness.gov.au/2008/06/identity/claims/credentialtype", false)
        },
        AppliesTo = new EndpointReference(appliesTo),
        Lifetime = new Lifetime(DateTime.UtcNow, DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(tokenLifeTimeMinutes)),
        RequestType = RequestTypes.Issue,
        KeyType = KeyTypes.Symmetric,
        TokenType = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.1#SAMLV1.1",
        // ActAs = This SecurityTokenElement need to be passed by the Host Service Providers.  
    };

    // Instantiate and invoke the client to get the security token
    var client = (WSTrustChannel) factory.CreateChannel();
    var response = client.Issue(rst);
    return response;
}
```

**.Net 6 Code**

```
public static async Task<IUSIService> OpenWithM2MAsync()
{
    var token = GetStsToken();
    var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
          .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
          .Build();

    var serviceProvider = ConfigurationsManager.ConfigureServices(configuration);

    var clientSettings = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<ClientSection>>().Value;

    var endpointElement = clientSettings.Endpoints
        .First(endpoint => string.Equals("USIServiceReference.IUSIService", endpoint.Contract, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

    if (endpointElement == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("No endpoint matching service contract was found");
    }

    var binding = ConfigurationsManager.CreateBinding(endpointElement.Binding, endpointElement.BindingConfiguration);
    var endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(endpointElement.Address);

    var factory = new ChannelFactory<IUSIService>(binding, endpointAddress);
    factory.Open();
    factory.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new MyIssuedTokenEndpointBehavior(token)); //Here is need to pass the token
    

    var channel = factory.CreateChannel();

    return channel;
}

public static System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityToken GetStsToken()
{
    HttpClient Client = new HttpClient();
    Uri uri = new Uri("https://softwareauthorisations.acc.ato.gov.au/R3.0/S007v1.3/service.svc");
    //X509Certificate2 cert = // from some store etc
    var envelope = BuildEnvelope(GetClientCertificateFromKeystore());
    
    using (HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri))
    {
        request.Content = new StringContent(envelope, Encoding.UTF8, "application/soap+xml");
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = Client.SendAsync(request).Result)
        {
            string responseContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            // Parse the SOAP response to extract the SAML token
            XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDocument.LoadXml(responseContent);

            //Here i need to convert response to SecurityToken
        }
    }            
    //return token;
}
```